# Bookmarklet to open an URL and inject remote js files

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

How to open an url and inject some js files on the page.

Something like:

```
javascript:var my_popup = window.open('http://www.XXXX.com');my_popup.document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://YYYY.com/js/c.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. the bookmarklet is only working for CURRENT page.